# How to resolve issue in Cassandra "ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We tried adding a new column to an existing table in Cassandra. It ended up giving an exception "org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch".

1. When we execute the command "describe " --> New columns was added.
2. when we tried to insert the data --> it throws an exception that "the newly added column does NOT exist".
3. We tried to recreate the table by dropping it --> Table gets dropped but while recreating it says table already exists.

Seems like some issue with Cassandra sync.

I want this issue to be resolved without any need to restart the Cassandra Nodes.

Can someone suggest the right approach to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you bounced your cluster? Theres a race condition if 2 parallel CREATE/ALTER TABLE calls are made. `nodetool resetlocalschema` useful to be called on nodes that dont match under `nodetool describecluster`

Comment: but the "nodetool describecluster" did not show me schema version difference. I did the rolling restart and then only it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rolling restart of the cluster resolved this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing memtables (nodetool flush) should resolve the issue.
Flushing does not require restarting cassandra whereas draining does.

See:
[Column family ID mismatch during ALTER TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928585/column-family-id-mismatch-during-alter-table)

Comment: Here's the command used: /opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/bin/nodetool flush -- mykeyspace mytable